# Nginx+GolangのアプリケーションにHTTP2を導入したい

Tags: go, nginx, http2

NginxとGoの[Echoフレームワーク](https://github.com/labstack/echo)を使ったアプリケーションにHTTP2での通信を実装したいです。そこでNginxとアプリケーションサーバの設定を以下のようにしました。

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server_tokens off;
}
```

**default.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  server_name ドメイン;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ドメイン/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ドメイン/privkey.pem;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE+RSAGCM:ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:!aNULL!eNull:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!DSS;

  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;';
  client_max_body_size 64M;

  # OCSP Staplingを有効にする
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ドメイン/fullchain.pem;

  # OCSP StaplingのためにはDNSリゾルバを指定する必要がある
  resolver 8.8.8.8;


  # Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
  location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect http:// https://;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:ポート;
  }

  location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /home/user1/public;
  }

  location ~ .*\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG|swf|SWF|css|CSS|js|JS|inc|INC|ico|ICO) {
    root /home/user1/public;
  }
}
```

**アプリケーションサーバの起動部分**

```
e.Run(standard.WithConfig(engine.Config{
            Address:     ":" + os.Getenv("PORT"),
            TLSCertfile: os.Getenv("CERT"),
            TLSKeyfile:  os.Getenv("KEY"),
        }))
```

しかし、Golangのサーバ単体でローカルでテストしたところHTTP2で通信出来ましたが、本番環境のNginxをリバースプロキシとして実行するとHTTP2ではなくなってしいます。
SSL通信はできています。pemファイルへのパーミッションの問題かと考えアプリケーションサーバをroot権限で実行してみたりもしましたができませんでした。

ローカルで動いていたのでNginxの設定ではないかと考えていますが、設定の不備などがわかりません。どのようにすればHTTP2での通信を実現できるのでしょうか。

ちなみにGolangでの設定例は[このサイト](https://echo.labstack.com/recipes/http2)を参考にしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の設定でTCP接続自体をプロキシすることで
goからhttp2のサービス(リッスンポート127.0.0.1:8443)が動きました。

**nginx.conf** (nginx1.9以降、streamモジュール有効)

```
events {
    worker_connections  768;
}

http {
    server {
        listen          80;
        listen          [::]:80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

stream {
    upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:8443 weight=5 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        proxy_pass backend;
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。これでできそうです。ただこれだと間にnginxを挟む意味がないようなきがします。画像やスクリプトだけでもhttp2で配信したいのですができないでしょうか。

Comment: upstreamは複数書けますのでロードバランサとしてnginxを使う意味はあります。

Comment: goから静的ファイルを配信するのはどうですか？

Comment: upstreamを複数書いて複数のサーバに負荷分散

Comment: upstreamを複数書いて複数のサーバに負荷分散のですね。Goから静的ファイルを配信できるのでupstreamと合わせてhttp2に対応できると思います。

Comment: あとnginxの設定ファイルに書いたSSLのセキュリティ設定は適用できるのでしょうか。

Comment: @zousan この質問に答えると上の回答が意味の無いものになります。何をしたいのかもう少し具体的にしてみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: @nobonoboさんの回答は十分有用であると思いますが、できればセキュリティを担保した状態でHTTP2を導入したいです。

Comment: go側のhttp2が必須ならこの回答です。フロントのセキュリティの方が重要でgo側http2が必須でないならgoのhttp2はやめる方がいいでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

nginxの一般的なhttp2プロキシサンプルのようにhttp2からhttpへの転送ではなく、http2をhttp2のまま転送したいのでしようか？

nginxは https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/923 のようにバックエンドプロトコルにhttp2サポートは無さそうです。

nghttpxなどのサポートされたフロントをお使いください。

Comment: 静的ファイルはnginxから直接配信できるようにしているのですが、それもhttp2にならないのはなぜでしょうか

Comment: nginxで静的ファイルをhttp2で配信したいのであれば質問の問題としてる範囲からはずれますが、default.confの内容をシンプルにすれば動きます。

Comment: もう少し具体的に教えていただくことは可能でしょうか

Comment: すいません、nginxはあまり詳しく無いので、、、。

Comment: nginx 1.9 以降のstream moduleでtcpのままプロキシできるかもしれません。go側はリモートアドレスを知る方法はなくなりますが。